# Should edit points be reverted when the question is closed / deleted?

Tags: discussion, editing, profile-page

I understand that when a question that I've edited is deleted, I also lose 1 edit from my edit count. I've been slowly losing some of my edit count, and I think it's extra discouraging for users to bother editing other users posts.

There is no extrinsic motivation to edit others posts besides an insignificant, almost unnoticed count, and even that is not a representation of the effort given to edit others posts, because goodness knows how many awful posts I've spent ages editing which were subsequently deleted and no trace of the time I invested is left.

Shouldn't I at least get to keep my measly 1 edit even when a post is deleted?

Comment: If you're hoping to a change in functionality (i.e. a [meta-tag:feature-request]), then this would be better off posted at MSE

Comment: Rather just discuss than propose, because the latter requires a lot of effort.

Comment: You would know better than me, is this data something you can pull from SEDE?

Comment: As far as discussion goes, I don't feel strongly either way. Edit count is not something I pay attention to

Comment: @JohnB I think it can be pulled from SEDE, but you also need to filter out edits on own posts and multi-edits, and I think there's still an issue with slight inaccuracy, if I recall correctly. That's not a quick or easy way to show a statistic anyway though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally prefer the edit points to not be subtracted. As you mention, there is effort put in each edit, and it's not likely for someone to build rep only on edits - new users need their edits approved, so editing every question that could get closed won't add up to a lot of rep.

On the other hand, I can imagine the reason why those points get subtracted (if this is done by design): Perhaps it's effort going in a direction that is not very useful (terrible questions that will end up closed, instead of edits for questions that get upvotes and favs).

**Editing is essential, and when it comes to questions that need some help it can be crucial in saving them.** If you feel you are losing too much rep for these edits, maybe you can focus on what type of questions you are editing, and try to rule out those that don't seem salvageable.

If you want to make this into a feature-request, I would agree with these points not getting lost when the question is closed.

Comment: To be as clear as possible, because I think count and rep can easily get confused here, I'm only talking about the count of how many edits I've done. I'm not bothered about the rep. In a few weeks/months my edit count appears to have gone from 420+ edits to 403.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you're worried about the "count" of edits instead of knowing you are on the positive side of improving the site I don't know what to say to you.  From what I can say now all you care about is the numbers.  So.. if that is all you care about think what happens when you don't make that edit, the site quality goes down, the efforts of the many others dwindles.  If a question was removed there was a good reason why, either by automation, a mod, or the OP.  If you aren't worried about how the site looks or if you feel the only validation you get about doing a good job for the community is from a number I don't know what to tell you but that this is silly.

Comment: Just want to be able to count how many edits I've really done. On the rest of it I have no comment.